# Having Trouble with Speech Recognition Module [python] in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: python, python-3.x, speech-recognition

I was trying the Python Speech Recognition Module on Ubuntu 20.04 and I am Facing many errors

This is the code I tried

```
import speech_recognition as sr

recognition = sr.Recognizer()
with sr.Microphone() as source:
    print("Speak Your Name")
    audio = recognition.listen(source)
    text = recognition.recognize_google(audio)
    print(text)
```

This is the error I am getting:

```
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1089:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
ALSA lib pcm.c:2642:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.rear
ALSA lib pcm.c:2642:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.center_lfe
ALSA lib pcm.c:2642:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.side
Cannot lock down 82280346 byte memory area (Cannot allocate memory)
Cannot lock down 82280346 byte memory area (Cannot allocate memory)
ALSA lib pcm_oss.c:377:(_snd_pcm_oss_open) Unknown field port
ALSA lib pcm_oss.c:377:(_snd_pcm_oss_open) Unknown field port
ALSA lib pcm_usb_stream.c:486:(_snd_pcm_usb_stream_open) Invalid type for card
ALSA lib pcm_usb_stream.c:486:(_snd_pcm_usb_stream_open) Invalid type for card
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1089:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
Cannot lock down 82280346 byte memory area (Cannot allocate memory
```

Answer (score 1):

Use sudo to start the script, and if that doesn't help check your mic settings.

Answer (score 0):

My microphone was picking a lot of background noise, so the solution was to set my microphone settings to an appropriate value [ʳᵉᶠ](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1019798/how-to-change-default-microphone-configuration-on-ubuntu-16-04#:%7E:text=Setting%20your%20system%20default%20input%20Device), but I was still receiving memory allocation errors, and that was fixed by using sudo while launching the script.